# How to update document by ID without using model

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have Card model and I have an API where I'm looking for a document by ID.

```
app.post("/api/postcomment", async (req,res) => {
  const data = req.body
  const reqUrl = req.headers.referer
  const re = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z0-9]*$)', 'i')
  const fixedUrl = reqUrl.match(re)

  try {
    await Card.update({_id: fixedUrl}, {$push:{'comments': data}})
    const card = await Card.findById(fixedUrl)
    return res.json(card)
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
})
```

It works fine. But now I have few more models. All should work the same way to them. But how can I make this code reusable for every model? 
Or maybe there is a way to pass a name of my model to API? and then use it like this:

```
app.post("/api/postcomment", async (req,res, modelName) => {
  const data = req.body
  const reqUrl = req.headers.referer
  const re = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z0-9]*$)', 'i')
  const fixedUrl = reqUrl.match(re)

  try {
    await modelName.update({_id: fixedUrl}, {$push:{'comments': data}})
    const item = await modelName.findById(fixedUrl)
    return res.json(item )
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution1:** You can create two helper functions and call the from the router. Both function accept the model object:

```
let updateDocument = (model, fixedUrl, data) => {
  return model.update({ _id: fixedUrl }, { $push: { comments: data }})
}

let getDocument = (model, fixedUrl) => {
  return model.findById(fixedUrl)
}

app.post("/api/postcomment", async (req, res, modelName) => {
  const data = req.body
  const reqUrl = req.headers.referer
  const re = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z0-9]*$)', 'i')
  const fixedUrl = reqUrl.match(re)

  try {
    await updateDocument(Card, fixedUrl, data)
    const item = await getDocument(Card, fixedUrl)
    return res.json(item )
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
})
```

**Solution2:** The much better solution is to create a base class (service), with the common functionality. And extend it for each model:

```
class BaseService {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  getDocument(data) {
    return this.model.findOne(...);
  }

  updateDocument(data) {
    return this.model.update(...);
  }
}

class CardService extends BaseService {
  constuctor() {
    super(Card);
  }
}
```